# Xamarin forms list view

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am developing for UWP using Xamarin Forms. I am uncertain which is the best way to code this image. If any one can help with XAML code for this design that would be great.

[image]

Comment: you can create your view by combining stacklayout and other basic controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tableview in Xamarin forums you can implement this easy way

Answer (score 0):

If the list of verifications is long, you can use list view and scroll view.